# How to list unique combinations in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe in pandas with columns. I want list only the unique combinations .How can do it.

```
**Input**

data[['Month','Ratio']]

Month  Ratio
3      0.7169653 
3      0.7169653      
3      0.7169653
6      0.6789213
6      0.6789213
7      0.2345671
7      0.2345671
7      0.2345671
7      0.2345671
12     0.5623451
12     0.5623451
12     0.5623451
1      0.9808901


**Expected Output**

Month  Ratio
3      0.7169653 
6      0.6789213
7      0.2345671
12     0.5623451
1      0.9808901
```

How to do this in python

Comment: `data.drop_duplicates()`.  Did you google anything before posting here?

Comment: `data.drop_duplicates(subset=['Month','Ratio'], inplace=True)` should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **`drop_duplicates()`** function

```
 Month_unique= data[['Month','Month_Ontime_Delivery_Ratio']].drop_duplicates()
```

This resolved the issue.